# How to make PostgreSQL behave like MongoDB with notablescan

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using the MongoDB parameter `notablescan: 1` to let queries fail during test execution if they don't use an index.

How could I achieve a similar behaviour with PostgreSQL? I want postgres to return and error when I run a query that doesn't use an index.

I tried Googling, asking a LLM engine so far but no clue

Comment: There is no possibilities to do that in PostGreSQL

Comment: Why? What is wrong with a sequential scan?

Comment: Isn't an index scan much more efficient?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do that in PostgreSQL. The best you can do is to run `EXPLAIN` on the query and examine the execution plan:

```
DO
$$DECLARE
   j jsonb;
BEGIN
   EXECUTE $_$EXPLAIN (FORMAT json) SELECT count(*) FROM doubles WHERE b = 42$_$ INTO j;
   IF j @? '$.**."Node Type" ? (@ == "Seq Scan")' THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'evil sequential scan';
   END IF;
END;$$;
```

This example uses PL/pgSQL to first get the execution plan, then it performs a JSONPATH test if any node is a sequential scan.

The question is what the reason behind that requirement is. There is nothing bad about sequential scans per se. If you are worried about queries that take too long, you could set the `statement_timeout` parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the code - that is something I can build up on.
Why is there nothing bad about a sequential scan? Isn't an index scan much more efficient?

Comment: Not always. If you have a shelf with 5 books, do you consult a library catalog? No, because sequentially scanning the 5 books is faster. Also, `pg_dump` performs sequential scans, and that is not a bad query that you have to optimize.

Comment: With 5 books no. But many times I have seen apps starting with very little data and then growing over years accumulating more and more data and become slow all the time. This can be easily avoided by using indexes from the beginning on

Comment: PostgreSQL will automatically switch to using indexes if the tables keep growing. You cannot test with a small data set to see the execution plans that PostgreSQL would use with lots of data.

Comment: So PostgreSQL creates indexes dynamically during operation? Is this feature always on by default? I mean - an index build can take up significant resources. What happens when you have a table with 9.000.000.000. events with different fields and with a new feature that you ship with a new release to the application you start accessing a field that has not been queried at all before. 
Wouldn't the application then experience a significant performance hit on the first query when PostgreSQL suddenly starts indexing that field?

Comment: No, PostgreSQL does not create indexes. You have to create indexes. For that, you have to test with as many rows of test data as you expect the database to have.

Comment: Alright, thank you for the clarification :)